# jQuery JS scroll to top on click works only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a page scroll to top when a link is clicked.
Heres what I got so far.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
    jQuery("ul.pager a").click(function() { 
       scroll(0,0);  
       return false;
  });
});
<script>
```

Problem with that code is that it works only on first click.

How to make it work every time I click on a link?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/794fn/3/

Comment: It looks like there's something else going on in your code that's messing things up. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQvAw/) that shows that your idea should work. Can you post more of your code, or link to an example or something?

Comment: Your `</script>` tag is wrong here. I don't know if that's the actual HTML you used, though. Can we have a jsFiddle?

Comment: Its not the script tag its just a typo here.

Comment: Problem could be that once i invoke that function the whole pager that should trigger that also gets refreshed but js code dosent.

Comment: so i dont make you guess too much heres a page http://www.visitcroatia.net/en/accomodations/hotels check the pager at the bottom it triggers the code and the code is in footer .. tnx

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use internal links (href="#top") instead of binding events with jQuery.

Comment: That solution is not possible in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
    jQuery("ul.pager a").live("click", function() { 
       scroll(0,0);  
       return false;
  });
});
```

try this

Comment: what if you move the script tag out of the pager that is getting refreshed to some other place?

Comment: Its not in a pager that is getting refreshed. script is there all the time and pager is refreshed which should trigger the function

Comment: can you give an example of the href attributes of links inside the page?

Comment: Tnx all for trying but I managed to solove it. Had to hack a bit Drupal views js but that seems to be the only solution for now. Now script loads every time pager loads and it works.